# Adding custom success and error messages for the create and edit views

Tags: react-admin

So in the docs it says just to add a prop on the edit component with an onSuccess / onFailure function and I've done that but navigating to the page to edit throws an error like this:
`` Warning: Unknown event handler property `onSuccess`. It will be ignored. ``

code here:

```
export const AffiliateEdit = (props) => {
  const notify = useNotify();
  const onSuccess = () => {
    notify('Affiliate saved successfully');
  }

  return (
    <Edit {...props} onSuccess={onSuccess}>
      <SimpleForm redirect="list">
        <ColorInput source="color" />
        <TextInput source="name" validate={[required()]} />
        <ReferenceInput
          source="network_id"
          reference="networks"
          validate={[required()]}
        >
          <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <TextInput
          source="reference"
          validate={[required()]}
          helperText="Please use all lower case, no spaces or underscores e.g affiliatename"
        />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  )
};
```

doc ref here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm figured it out, just needed to update react-admin lol